# SharePoint alert Office 2010 email cuts off table

Tags: alert, office-integration

I have an alert set up for a discussion board. We have been using Office 03 just fine, email comes in, the body is shown fully, everything is great. However, when we transferred to Office 2010, not sure if its Outlook 2010 or Excel 2010, but when a table is copied from Excel into an Outlook email, the table is cutoff. The same procedure was used in Office 2003 and the table stays in tact. It's as though the only thing that shows in a couple of column headings (not even all of them), and all of the rest of the rows are cut off and out of view. Is there a known issue with Office 2010 and SharePoint 2007 not working together for this issue?

I've tried pasting options (keep formatting and values only), i've tried many different table sizes, i've tried pasting as picture, i've tried specified column and row sizes, nothing seems to work. Its like Outlook 2010 REALLY doesn't like keeping the tables in tact.

HTML Source of generated email

```
<html  dir = ltr>
 <head>
 <base href="mysite">
<style>
<!--
.headertop1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.headercontent {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 16pt;
}
.headercontent em {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.breadcrumb td {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
.breadcrumb a{
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
.content {
  margin-top:6px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom:solid 1px #9ca3ad;
}
.toolbar {
  border: 1px solid #e8eaec;
  background-color: #f8f8f9;
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-bottom:6px;
  padding-right:3px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
.toolbarbutton a, .toolbarsep {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: .68em;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
.toolbarbutton a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.toolbarsep {
  color:#c7cbd1;
}
.spacer {  
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 1px;
}
.formline,  .noheight {
  height: 1px;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 1px;
}
.formlabel, .formbody, .digestlabel, .altdigestlabel, .deletedlabel, .altdeletedlabel  {
  font-family: tahoma; 
  font-size:8pt; 
  padding: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.formlabel, .digestlabel, .altdigestlabel, .deletedlabel, .altdeletedlabel  {
  color: #616a76;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
.rulerow  {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #9ca3ad;
  height:0px;
  font-size:1px;
  line-height:0px;
}
.digestlabel a, .altdigestlabel a {
}
.digestlabel a:hover, .altdigestlabel a:hover {
}
.formbody {
  color: #000000;
}
.edited{
  text-decoration:line-through;
  color:#9ca3ad;
}
.descriptiontext {
  color: #9ca3ad;
  font-family: tahoma; 
  font-size: 8pt; 
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:7px;
}
.formline {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D7DEAC;
}
.editedicon, .newicon, .deletedicon {
  color:#000000;
  font-family: Small Fonts,  Tahoma, Verdana, Sans Serif;
  font-size: 7pt;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-right:3px;
  padding-bottom:1px;
  padding-leftt:2px;
  position: relative;
  top:2px;
  margin-right:8px;
  margin-left:8px;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.editedicon {
  background-color:#ffffcc;
}
.newicon {
  background-color:#b1faa2;
}
.deletedIcon {
  background-color:#ffcccc;
 }
.messagespace {
  color: #5D6437;
  font-family: tahoma; 
  font-size: 8pt; 
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:7px;
}
.editedexample {
  background: #FFFFBF;
  padding:1px;
}
.vh, .vb, .altvb, .deleted, .altdeleted{
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 8pt;  
  font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
  padding-left:  5px; 
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.vb, .altvb, .deleted, .altdeleted, .digestlabel, .altdigestlabel, .formlabel, .formbody {
  border-bottom:solid 1px #e8eaec;
  padding-top:2px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
}
.vb div.nobr, .altvb div.nobr {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.vh {
  color:#76808e;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-top:7px;
  padding-bottom:6px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.vb, .altvb {
  color:#616a76;
}
.altvb, .altdigestlabel, .altdeleted, .altdeletedlabel, .formlabel, .formbody {
  background: #f8f8f9; 
}
.digesttext {
  color: #000000;
}
.deleted, .deletedlabel, .altdeleted, .altdeletedlabel {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color:#9ca3ad;
}
.deleted a, .altdeleted a {
  color:#9ca3ad;
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
-->
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table class="headertop1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr><td class="headercontent">
    <table class="breadcrumb" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td><a href="mysite">Test Bed</a></td></tr></table> <em>again6</em> has been added
   </td>
  </tr></table>  
  <table class="content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
     <table class="toolbar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tr><td>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="MySite">Modify my alert settings</a></td>
        <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
        <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="MySite">View  again6</a></td>
        <td class="toolbarsep">|</td>
        <td class="toolbarbutton"><a href="MySite">View  Test Discussion</a></td> 
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td></tr></table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr><td colspan="3"class="spacer"> &nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">Subject:</td>
    <td class="formbody"> again6&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">Body:</td>
    <td class="formbody"> <div class=ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451><div>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft SafeHTML"><style>
.ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 p.MsoNormal, .ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 li.MsoNormal, .ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 div.MsoNormal
{margin:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;font-size:11.0pt;font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';}
.ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 a:link, .ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 span.MsoHyperlink
{color:blue;text-decoration:underline;}
.ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 a:visited, .ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
{color:purple;text-decoration:underline;}
.ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 span.EmailStyle17
{font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';color:windowtext;}
.ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 .MsoChpDefault
{font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';}
@page WordSection1
{size:8.5in 11.0in;margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
.ExternalClassA3F9A4A6074C41AFA85CA541B91A9451 div.WordSection1
{page:WordSection1;}

</style></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=1364 style="width:1023.0pt;margin-left:-1.15pt;border-collapse:collapse"><tr style="height:15.0pt"><td width=83 nowrap style="width:62.0pt;border:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt"><p class=MsoNormal><span style="color:black">3/28/2011</span></p></td><td width=65 nowrap style="width:49.0pt;border-top:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt"><p class=MsoNormal><span style="color:black">Â Â Â Â Â  ARK</span></p></td><td width=64 nowrap style="width:48.0pt;border-top:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt"><p class=MsoNormal><span style="color:black">Â Â Â Â Â Â  ILL</span></p></td><td width=64 nowrap style="width:48.0pt;border-top:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt"><p class=MsoNormal><span style="color:black">Â Â Â Â Â  OH</span></p></td><td width=77 nowrap valign=bottom style="width:58.0pt;border-top:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt"><p class=MsoNormal><span style="color:black">Column1</span></p></td><td width=64 nowrap style="width:48.0pt;border-top:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:15.0pt"><p class=MsoNormal><span style="color:black">Â Â Â Â  LOR</span></p></td><td width=67 nowrap style="width:50.0pt;border-top:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid #95B3D7 1.0pt;border-right:none;background:#DCE6F1;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;he
</div>
</div>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">Last Updated:</td>
    <td class="formbody"> 4/8/2011 10:26 AM&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">E-Mail From:</td>
    <td class="formbody"> Mike&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="formlabel">E-Mail Subject:</td>
    <td class="formbody"> again6&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="altvb">&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan=3 class="descriptiontext">Last Modified 4/8/2011 10:26 AM by Mike</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the html source of the generated email?  Just a wild guess, but it could be due to the formatting of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to SharePoint 2010 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Please specify exactly what parameters have changed. Eg you changed to office 2010, but is outlook and SharePoint version the same?

Also add a sceenshot showing the issue?

I am still a bitnunclear on where SharePoint comes into the picture, other than being the trigger of the mail. This means your question is borderline off-topic. Depending on how you describe The relation your post might be moved to Stack Overflow.

If you upgraded from earlier versions of Outlook, the rendering engine changed substantially in 2007 and 2010 using word to render html mail. This affected copy paste from other apps. Check out [this](http://fuelyourcoding.com/outlook-2010-and-html-email/) article and its links.

Comment: It seems the problem is with the e-mail generated by SP, so I'd suggest that's on topic. Unless I'm missing something? :)

Comment: I like this answer, but even though the email is sent to SharePoint, the email that is received is an alert (if set up). The alert arrives whenever the SP email reaches its destination, being a discussion board. This could be on to something, but ultimately how would I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The HTML is invalid! You got multiple '</head>' and '<body>' tags.

Comment: There is also a broken <td tag.  Listen to Wictor and clean that up.  =D

Comment: That was pasted directly from the email source. I think its because the email is in html format with an html body format.

Comment: Also, this isn't an answer to the question at hand. Can you provide further assistance?

Comment: Since the question is about problems with HTML formatting, the fact that the sample is invalid (actually it is not well-formed), is a valid answer. Can you clean up the HTML in the question? - then perhaps people will be able to provide further assistance. Thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with HTML formatting, and that code was not written, but rather pasted directly from the email that was generated from SharePoint. It's not my fault its invalid.